# Python Embedding with IPython: WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, c++, ipython

Trying to run:

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("import IPython\n"
                     "IPython.embed()\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

compiled with mignw64 gcc 4.6.0 ( `g++ -I /c/prog64/Python27/include t.cpp /c/prog64/Python27/libs/libpython27.a` ) under Windwos 7 I get the error:

```
$ a.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\prog64\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 290, in embed
    shell = InteractiveShellEmbed.instance(**kwargs)
  File "c:\prog64\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\configurable.py", line 354, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\prog64\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 92, in __init__
    display_banner=display_banner
  File "c:\prog64\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\interactiveshell.py", line 328, in  __init__
    **kwargs
  File "c:\prog64\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 483, in __init__
    self.init_readline()
  File "c:\prog64\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1817, in init_readline
    import IPython.utils.rlineimpl as readline
  File "c:\prog64\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\rlineimpl.py", line 21, in <module>
    _rl = __import__(_rlmod_name)
  File "c:\prog64\python27\lib\site-packages\readline.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyreadline.rlmain import Readline
  File "c:\prog64\python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import unicode_helper, logger, clipboard, lineeditor, modes, console
  File "c:\prog64\python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .console import *
  File "c:\prog64\python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\console.py", line 610, in <module>
    msvcrt = cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_msvcrt())
  File "C:\prog64\Python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\prog64\Python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 applicationTraceback (most recent call last):
```

Note that other commands in the `PyRun_SimpleString` do work; also, in a command line python session:

```
import IPython
IPython.embed()
```

works.

I expect the problem is related to MSVCR90.DLL where the _dlopen looks for, and the fact that g++ links to the "normal" MSVCRT.DLL. Compiling with VS2008 is no easy option. Same error message is seen when compiling with VS2010. Python setup is Anaconda Python 2.7.8 64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem indeed is related to msvcr90.dll. Way to solve it is to link the program against msvcr90.dll. However, to link against msvcr90.dll you need to have a manifest or you will get a runtime error. This manifest looks like:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

which I extracted from python.exe with a text editor and named `msvcr90.manifest`. This manifest is linked into the application using the resource file `msvcr90.rc`

```
#include "winuser.h"
1 RT_MANIFEST msvcr90.manifest
```

which in turned can be compiled into an object file using:

```
windres msvcr90.rc msvcr90.o
```

Than, compilation of the program with this resource file and msvcr90.dll becomes:

```
g++ -I /c/prog64/Python27/include t.cpp /c/prog64/Python27/libs/libpython27.a msvcr90.o msvcr90.dll
```

where I copied msvcr90.dll from c:/Windows/winsxs/amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b/msvcr90.dll

Input for this came from

- https://cournape.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/how-to-embed-a-manifest-into-a-dll-with-mingw-tools-only
- [Manifest being ignored in mingw app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255591/manifest-being-ignored-in-mingw-app)
- http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MS_resource_compiler
- https://lists.launchpad.net/kicad-developers/msg09473.html

and a couple of other web pages which explained me how to do this.